# Why should I insert wp_head() for wp_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have add this code to functions.php but startwordpress_scripts() function didn't run.

```
function startwordpress_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'startwordpress_scripts' );
```

So I added following code in header.php and they worked well.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Now I want to know the magic role of wp_head() function.
Thanks.

Comment: What specific question do you have that's not documented? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head

Comment: if you don't add `<?php wp_head(); ?>` then what ever `header.php` your theme is using will not be added to the html output for the page. Chances are, most of your other scripts and libraries are linked via in the `header.php` so if that's not loaded, everything in it is not loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In WordPress, `actions` and `filters` are considered as [hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks). Hooks allow us to modify the WordPress default behaviour without modifying the code found in the core.

Anytime you have an `add_action('xxx', 'callback')`, the `callback` function will be called when `do_action('xxx')` is executed.

In other words: when you have `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'startwordpress_scripts' );`, it means that WordPress will run `startwordpress_scripts()` when `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')` is executed.

Now, let's look at the code in the WordPress core.

If you look at its function definition, `wp_head()` is a "shortcut" to `do_action( 'wp_head' );`

```
function wp_head() {
        /**
         * Print scripts or data in the head tag on the front end.
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         */
        do_action( 'wp_head' );
}
```

In other words, `wp_head()` will execute all callbacks that were defined with [`add_action('wp_head')`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

If you now look at the `wp-includes/default-filters.php` file, you'll see:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts',1 );
```

It means that when `wp_head()` is encountered in your template, a function called `wp_enqueue_scripts()` is being executed, since it is hooked to `wp_head`, shown in the line of code above.

the function definition of `wp_enqueue_scripts()` is:

```
function wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    /**
     * Fires when scripts and styles are enqueued.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

The `do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );` above is what tells WordPress to execute the callback function of all `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback')` that are defined.

In short:

1. `wp_head()` calls `do_action('wp_head')`
2. `do_action('wp_head')` executes callback functions of all `add_action('wp_head','callback')`
3. `wp_enqueue_scripts()` is one callback of `add_action('wp_head','callback')`
4. `wp_enqueue_scripts()` calls `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')`
5. `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')` executes callback functions of all `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','callback')`
6. `startwordpress_scripts()` is one callback of `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','callback')`
7. Your JS/CSS defined in `startwordpress_scripts()` are included

Comment: Thanks RRikesh!
Very clear description, easy to read and understand.
I can't find such wonderful answer ever.

Comment: why does replacing wp_head() with do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts') not work to load scripts and styles?. The callback runs but the styles are not applied for some odd reason

Answer (score 1):

> The wp_head action hook is triggered within the  section
>   of the user's template by the wp_head() function.

If you remove wp_head() function then all action **add_action('wp_head','your_custom_action');** is not working also plugin also use wp_head action action to add css or js.

If you remove wp_head function from header.php file then below function not add any JS in header.

```
function startwordpress_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'startwordpress_scripts' );
```

If you want to remove wp_head() function then you need to add like below.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css' href='http://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.3.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='blog-css' href='http://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/css/blog.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.siteurl.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.3'></script>
```

See Link for [**wp_enqueue_script**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function and args

Comment: @WhiteSnow you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors in your code shown above and I've double checked to see it working correctly in a fresh WP install. It should not be the cause of your errors.

Take a look at the DEBUG section of the codex to change that. This might need to be dropped into your wp-config.php.

```
// allow debugging 
defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) or define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// log errors to wp-content/debug.log
defined( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG' ) or define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// show errors on screen
defined( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY' ) or define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```