# wp_enqueue_scripts not being called

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen many questions at StackOverflow and other websites about why 'wp_enqueue_scripts' not working but none of was what I was looking for.

I want to import a script to my Wordpress theme and I have copied one code snipped from main the main developer Wordpress website.

I have the following code in my 'functions.php'and output is 'OUTPUT 1OUTPUT 4'.
It seems 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts()' never gets call.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    echo "OUTPUT 2";
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    echo "OUTPUT 3";
}
echo "OUTPUT 1";
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
echo "OUTPUT 4";
```

Comment: Do you see any changes when you replace `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );` with `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `wpdocs_theme_name_scripts()` will not be called after `echo "OUTPUT 1";` and before `echo "OUTPUT 4";`

`add_action()` will only register a callback which will be ran when `wp_head()` is encountered. You can find more details about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41339732/1370034).

Did you add `wp_head()` in the theme? It is normally added in `header.php` just before the `</head>` tag, something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much after adding `<?php wp_head(); ?>` things worked

Answer (score 4):

For anyone getting this problem in an **admin** page, use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

[Documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!  This was breaking my brain!

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
     /* This code is use in function.php */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );

    function mytheme_scripts() {
    echo "Helllo";
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-owlcaroselcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css', array( 'mytheme-style' ), '20150312' );
       echo "Helllo1";
    }
   /* ****** */
     ?>
     use in header.php with wp_head() function
    <html>
    <head>
     <?php wp_head();?>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: didn't make any difference, I added debugging 'echo' output is still the same. mytheme_scripts() doesn't even get called

Comment: Please explain your answer